# How to render a graph (DOT or GraphML format) on HTML web page - using JGraphT or GraphStream

Tags: java, html, graph

I have an existing Java application that, among other functions, provides a representation of call graphs between various entities of a system. I want to be able to display a visual representation of a graph on a web page. I have been looking at a couple of tools that seem promising: JGraphT (https://jgrapht.org) and GraphStream (https://graphstream-project.org).

I've been able to create simple graphs with nodes and edges and have been able to output the data in GraphML, DOT (Graphviz) and SVG formats. All of these files are essentially text files, formatted in the respective file formats.

I'm struggling with getting these graphs to render as a visual graph on an HTML web page. The graphs *do not* need to be interactive. I have added endpoints to serve up files containing the simple graphs generated by my experimentation, but I can't seem to get them to render in a browser. The closest I got was the SVG file, and it looked horrible - nothing like what was displayed in a "viewer" provided with the GraphStream library. Everything else produces nothing, or I just get the raw text format file displayed. In some cases, I'm not sure if I'm using the correct MIME type. It's as though something is missing, but I don't know what.

Has anyone used either of these libraries and successfully rendered graphs in a web page? Are there other libraries I may have missed? Maybe I need to convert the graphs into an image format and render that (I'm not seeing anything in either API that supports this)? Maybe I need to hand this off to some other technology (Javascript, etc.)? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.